# How to properly start nextQuestion method by pressing OK button in a popup dialog?

Tags: java, android

In my quiz game, after wrong answer I call a popup with an Intent for result. In that popup I have an OK button. I need, after user press OK button, to load next question. But now, I see in background next question loaded, even though my popup is not closed. Here's my code:

```
static final int MY_REQUEST = 0;

Intent i = new Intent(Kviz.this, Popup_pogresno.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, MY_REQUEST);


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        nextQuestion();
    }
```

And my popup class (it's a Theme.Dialog activity):

```
public class Popup_pogresno extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button ok;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.popup);

        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPopupOK);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });



       }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

So, I need the next question NOT to load UNTIL I press the OK button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a result code in `Popup_pogresno` Activity, and check this result code in `Kviz` activity on the basis of request code. If result code is ok the call the function `nextQuestion()`

set result code as follow and check in `Kviz` for is result code.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Kviz.this, Popup_pogresno.class);

startActivityForResult(i, MY_REQUEST);
```

set result code on ok button click in `Popup_pogresno` :

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);        
finish();
```

check for result code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST) {

     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
          nextQuestion();          
     }
     if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
         //Write your code if there's no result
     }
  }
}
```